# redirect based on user role stored in mysql database

Tags: php

I've made a website that users can now successfully login to but depending on which group the user is in, I would like to redirect them to different pages after logging in. I have a database with a row "training_group" and if for example, they are in group 2013_1, they would be directed to homepage_20131.php after logging in.

I've been looking for tutorials online and have found a possible solution with a switch function? but I am unsure of how/where to implement this. I just started learning php and would be grateful for any advice given!

Right now, my login page looks like this:

```
<?php
include 'core/init.php'; 
if (empty($_POST) === false) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    if (empty($username) === true || empty($password) === true) {
        $errors[] = 'please input a username and password first! ';
    } else if (user_exists($username) === false)    {
        $errors[] = 'We could not locate you in our database.';
    }    
    $login = login($username, $password);
    if ($login === false) {
        $errors [] = 'That username/password combination is incorrect';
    }    
    else {
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $login;
        header('Location:logged_in/templates/logged_in_home.php');
        exit ();
    }
}
else {
    $errors [] = 'No data received';
}

include 'includes/overall/header.php';

if (empty ($errors) === false) {
    ?>
    <h2>We tried to log you in, but...</h2>
    <?php
    echo output_errors($errors);
}
include 'includes/overall/footer.php'; 
?>
```

Comment: Do you understand how to connect / query the database and retrieve information?

Comment: to start, your `login($username, $password);` should return more than just the user_id, as I am assuming your group/permission is located in the same table/mechanism.  have that process return the group, then include that in your `header()` statement.

Comment: FYI `empty('0')` and `empty(' ')` are true - hopefully none of your users are using `0`or spaces as their username and/or password.

Comment: Did you ever come right as this has become my nightmare as well, also using the code form php academy

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple snippets that might get you going in the right direction.

```
function login($username, $password){
    //... your login code .. database call
    if($validLogin){
        $user_id = id from database;
        $group_id = id from database;
        $return = array('user_id' => $user_id, 'group_id' => $group_id);
    }
    else{
        $return = false;
    }

    return $return;
}

$userinfo = login($username, $password);
if ($userinfo === false) {
    $errors [] = 'That username/password combination is incorrect';
}    
else {
    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $userinfo['user_id'];
    $_SESSION['group_id'] = $userinfo['group_id'];

    $page = 'homepage_' . str_replace('_', '', $userinfo['group_id'] . '.php';
    header('Location:' . $page);
    exit ();
}
```

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for all the replies! I do know how to retrieve information and I will be assigning the users their own login/pw so I'll make sure there's no spaces and 0. My training_group is in the same table as the other user info(username/pw). From what I am understanding, I have to retrieve that info and then assign a page in the header() statement? I don't think I have enough knowledge to do that bymyself. Does anyone have any suggestions on tutorials or what my next steps would be? Thanks!